# NULL value while inserting foreign key using laravel 8

Tags: jquery, mysql, laravel

I have these migrations files :

Table castings

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('castings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id_casting');
            $table->string('nom');
            $table->string('prenom');
    }
```

Table Projet :

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('projets', function (Blueprint $table) {
              $table->increments('id_projet');
              $table->string('numero_projet',10);
              $table->integer('id_client')->unsigned();
              $table->integer('id_agence_conseil')->unsigned();
              $table->integer('id_agence_production')->unsigned();
              $table->integer('id_agence_casting')->unsigned();
              $table->string('description',255);
              $table->date('date_tournage');
              $table->date('date_premiere_diffusion');
              $table->integer('id_filiale')->unsigned();
              $table->integer('id_createur')->unsigned();
              $table->integer('actif')->default('1');
              $table->timestamps();
              $table->foreign('id_client')->references('id_client')->on('clients');
              $table->foreign('id_agence_conseil')->references('id_agence_conseil')->on('agences_conseil');
               $table->foreign('id_agence_production')->references('id_agence_production')->on('agences_production');
               $table->foreign('id_agence_casting')->references('id_agence_casting')->on('agences_casting');
               $table->foreign('id_filiale')->references('id_filiale')->on('filiales');
               $table->foreign('id_createur')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }
```

And table projets_castings

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('projets_castings', function (Blueprint $table) {
             $table->increments('id_projet_casting');
             $table->integer('id_projet')->nullable()->unsigned();
             $table->integer('id_casting')->nullable()->unsigned();
             $table->integer('id_contrat')->nullable()->unsigned();
             $table->integer('actif')->default('1');
             $table->timestamps();
             $table->foreign('id_projet')->references('id_projet')->on('projets');
             $table->foreign('id_casting')->references('id_casting')->on('castings');
            $table->foreign('id_contrat')->references('id_contrat')->on('contrats');

        });
    }
```

And I have the following models :

Projet Model :

```
class Casting extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
   
     protected $fillable = ["id_casting",
        "nom", "prenom" 
    ];
 
 protected $primaryKey = 'id_casting';
public function projets()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(App\Models\Projet::class, 'projet_casting');
    }
}
```

Projet Model :

```
class Projet extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

     protected $fillable = ["id_projet",
        "numero_projet", "id_client" , "id_agence_conseil","id_agence_production","id_agence_casting","description","date_tournage","date_premiere_diffusion","id_filiale","id_createur","actif"
    ];
     protected $primaryKey = 'id_projet';
public function castings()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(App\Models\Casting::class, 'projet_casting');
    }
}
```

And Projet_Casting Model :

```
class Projet_Casting extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ["id_projet_casting", "id_projet","id_casting","id_contrat",
       "actif"
    ];
 
 /* protected $guarded = [];*/
 protected $primaryKey = 'id_projet_casting';

 protected $table = 'projets_castings';
}
```

I'm using the following controleer to insert in Projet Table and Projet_Castiong table in the same time :

```
                 $projets = new Projet();
                 $projets->numero_projet = $request['numero_projet'];
                 $projets->id_client = $request['id_client'];
                 $projets->id_agence_conseil = $request['id_agence_conseil'];
                 $projets->id_agence_production = $request['id_agence_production'];
                 $projets->id_agence_casting = $request['id_agence_casting'];
                 $projets->description = $request['description'];
                 $projets->date_tournage = $date;
                 $projets->date_premiere_diffusion = $datee_diffusion;
                 $projets->id_filiale = Auth::user()->id_filiale;
                 $projets->id_createur = Auth::user()->id;
                 $projets->save();
   
                 $data = $request->input('rows');


                 foreach($data as $key => $value) 
                 {

                     Projet_Casting::create([
                        'id_projet' =>  $projets->id,
                        'id_casting' => $value['id_casting'],
                        'id_contrat' => $value['id_modele_contrat'],
                        ]);

                 }
```

So the problem the id_projet in Projet_Casting gets always the value Null

The data is inserted into table:projets and is inserted into table : projets_castings but in table:projets_casting the id_projets get value: NULL.

[image]

**UPDATE**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("body").on("click", ".add_new_frm_field_btn", function() {
    var random = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000); //generate random values..
    var index = $(".form_field_outer").find(".form_field_outer_row").length + 1;
    //added data-index and outer..class
    $(".form_field_outer").append(`<div class="col-12 outer" data-index="${index}_${random}"><div class="card-body form_field_outer_row"> <div class="form-row"><div class="form-group col-md-4"> <label for="inputState">Casting</label><select id="id_casting" class="form-control" name="rows[${index}][id_casting]">
    <option selected>Choose...</option><option data-id="{{$casting->id_casting}}" value="{{$casting->id_casting}}">{{$casting->nom.' '.$casting->prenom}}</option> </select></div><div class="form-group col-md-4"><label for="inputState">Type de contrat</label><select id="id_modele_contrat" class="form-control" name="rows[${index}][id_modele_contrat]"> <option selected>Choose...</option><option>...</option> </select></div><div class="card-body "><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning mb-1 remove_node_btn_frm_field">Delete</button></div>
    </div></div></div> `);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<form method="POST" id="projetform" class="myForms" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="card mb-4">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="mb-4">Projet</h5>
          <!-- <form id="projetform" method="post" action="ajout_projet" class="myForms"  enctype="multipart/form-data"> -->

          <input type="hidden" id="id_projet" name="id_projet" />
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputAddress">Numéro de projet</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="numero_projet" name="numero_projet" placeholder="Description">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-xl-8 col-left">
      <div class="card mb-4">
        <div class="card-body">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary mb-1 add_new_frm_field_btn">Ajouter un nouveau casting</button>
          </br>
          </br>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">

              <div class="card mb-4 form_field_outer  ">
                <div class="card-body form_field_outer_row outer" data-index="1">
                  <input type="hidden" id="id_projet_casting" name="id_projet_casting" />
                  <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                      <label for="inputState">Casting</label>
                      <select class="form-control" name="rows[1][id_casting]" id="id_casting">
                        <option selected>Choose...</option>
                        @foreach($castings as $casting)
                        <option data-id="{{$casting->id_casting}}" value="{{$casting->id_casting}}">{{$casting->nom.' '.$casting->prenom}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                      <label for="inputState">Type de contrat</label>
                      <select id="id_modele_contrat" class="form-control" name="rows[1][id_modele_contrat]">
                        <option selected>Choose...</option>
                        @foreach($models_contrat as $model_contrat)
                        <option data-id="{{$model_contrat->id_modele_contrat}}" value="{{$model_contrat->id_modele_contrat}}">{{$model_contrat->modele_contrat}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body ">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning mb-1 remove_node_btn_frm_field">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>


                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>


</div>
<button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-1">Add</button>
</div>
```

Please help

Comment: Where is the connection to jquery?

Comment: @Reporter, please check my Update

Comment: Have you checked that in your database is exesting a valid value  in blamed column?

Comment: wich columns ? id_projet ?

Comment: Yes. May be you should disable the possibility for nullable to check if the dabase received an unwanted null value. Have you defined a start value for this database column? Incrementing a null value creates another null value.

Comment: I get message: `"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Le champ 'id_projet' ne peut être vide (null)`

Comment: Have you also read my second question, in my comment above?

Comment: that means adding a default value to id_projet column ?

Comment: No a start value is not the same as a default value.

Comment: no it is not auto incerement in projets_casting table

Comment: it is a foreign key

Comment: In my eyes is not a good idea that a foreign key can be null. Check what data your backend does received.